# Is there a way to find all the possible inputs for one output?

Tags: arduino

For a class project, I am using a servo controlled arm to pick up and transport blocks and rings to a specific position. To control the arm I am able to use a `.setPosition` command with inputs of Stretch and Height. I am also able to manually move the arm and see the final servo positions. However, the stretch and height variables from `.setPosition` are pushed through a formula that changes them to a final value that is written to the servo. I am wondering if there is a way to look at all the possible arrangements of variables stretch and height to get the final servo positions that I need.

```
xx =_stretch*_stretch+_height*_height;

xxx=ARM_B2-ARM_A2+xx;

angleB =acos((_stretch*xxx+_height*sqrt(4.0*ARM_B2*xx-xxx*xxx))/(xx*2.0*ARM_B))* RAD_TO_DEG;


angleA =acos((_stretch*xxx-_height*sqrt(4.0*ARM_A2*xx-xxx*xxx))/(xx*2.0*ARM_A))* RAD_TO_DEG;
```

Angle `A` and `B` are my final position that is know. As well as ARM_A/2,ARM_B/2, as well as RAD_TO_DEG. Stretch and Height are the only unknown variables

Comment: This isn't related to arduino, isn't it? You want to solve your formula for stretch and height. Have you tried this?

Comment: The servos are controlled by an onboard arduino so I did not know if there was anything specific that I would be able to do within the arduino program.